# How to retrieve a subset of a class using Lambda expressions

Tags: java, mongodb, retrofit

I have a class called QuizQuestionswhich contains (strClassName,strSubjectName,strQuestionName,strOption1,strOption2 etccc...)

To retrieve this class object from mongodb after certain filtering, i am using below code and working fine:

```
List<QuizQuestions> returnQuizQuestions=new ArrayList<QuizQuestions>();

        List<QuizQuestions> listClsQuizMapping=clsQuizService.findAll();

        List<QuizQuestions> listOfQuizQuestions= listClsQuizMapping.stream()
                .filter(t->t.getStrClassName().equals(className))
                .filter(t->t.getStrSubjectName().equals(subjectName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But what i wanted is, only portion of this class like strQuestionName,strOption1,strOption2 etc...

How can i do this?
Do i need to create another class with these fields(**strQuestionName,strOption1,strOption2**) and return?

Comment: That would be a sensible approach, yes.

Comment: You should also use a database query to get them rather than getting all the questions from the database and then filter them. The whole point of a database is to be able to execute queries,